# Extract rows with consecutive zero values if they are preceded by significant values in R

Tags: r, lag, cumsum, lead

I'm working with a dataset in R called "data," originating from data collection on a Fronius inverter. This dataset contains one record per minute and a column named "pac_w," which represents the wattage of generated energy. The inverter has a protection system that interrupts energy generation in case of overvoltage. When this happens, the "pac_w" column is recorded as zero for four consecutive minutes (remembering that each row represents one minute), and it takes an additional two minutes to stabilize energy generation. These interruptions have occurred frequently in recent months, significantly impacting energy generation.

Example below with real data.

EDIT

Now with more rows.

```
pac_w <- c(3336,3294,0,0,0,0,742,1620,2530,3438,2626,3704,2321,3088,1672,2722,
           1953,0,0,0,0,836,1746,2654,3566,0,0,0,0,995,1908,2800)

day_energy_wh <- c(2479,2536,2555,2555,2555,2555,2560,2580,2615,2665,2717,2766,
                   2811,2868,2903,2944,2966,2979,2979,2979,2979,2986,3008,3045,
                   3097,3097,3097,3097,3097,3106,3131,3171)

date_time <- c("2023-12-23,08:13:00","2023-12-23,08:14:00","2023-12-23,08:15:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:16:00","2023-12-23,08:17:00","2023-12-23,08:18:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:19:00","2023-12-23,08:20:00","2023-12-23,08:21:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:22:00","2023-12-23,08:23:00","2023-12-23,08:24:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:25:00","2023-12-23,08:26:00","2023-12-23,08:27:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:28:00","2023-12-23,08:29:00","2023-12-23,08:30:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:31:00","2023-12-23,08:32:00","2023-12-23,08:33:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:34:00","2023-12-23,08:35:00","2023-12-23,08:36:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:37:00","2023-12-23,08:38:00","2023-12-23,08:39:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:40:00","2023-12-23,08:41:00","2023-12-23,08:42:00",
               "2023-12-23,08:43:00","2023-12-23,08:44:00")

data <- data.frame(pac_w,day_energy_wh,date_time)
```

My goal is to estimate how many watt-hours the inverter was unable to generate due to this overvoltage protection.

The day_energy_wh column shows the accumulated energy for the day up to the time in the date_time column.

I want to estimate the energy not generated by calculating the average between the value immediately before the failure (in case 3294) and the value after stabilization (in case 2530)

```
(3294 + 2530) / 2 = 2912
```

In the example data, the estimate of how many watt-hours the inverter stopped generating is 252.

```
round(sum(2912 - pac_w[3:8])/60) = 252
```

At the beginning and end of the day it is common to have low values and even values equal to zero. So I only want to estimate the energy not generated when the value of pac_w immediately before the four values equal to zero is equal to or greater than 500.

EDIT

r2evans, your first solution presents correct values, but is not immune to variation in the number of consecutive zeros.

The second solution is not affected by the variation of consecutive zeros, but something means that only the first calculation relating to the occurrences of consecutive zeros has the correct value.

```
r <- rle(data$pac_w == 0)

four0 <- setdiff(which(r$values), c(1L, length(r$values)))

four0 <- four0[r$lengths[four0 + 1] >= 3]

lapply(four0, function(f0) {
  indprev <- sum(r$lengths[1:(f0-1)])
  indtween <- (f0-1):sum(r$lengths[1:f0])+2
  indnext <- max(indtween)+1
  val <- sum(
    mean(data$pac_w[ c(indprev, indnext) ]) - data$pac_w[indtween]
  ) / 60
  cbind(data[indprev+1,], data.frame(lost = val))
}) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)

#   pac_w day_energy_wh           date_time     lost
# 3      0          2555 2023-12-23,08:15:00 251.8333 # correct
# 18     0          2979 2023-12-23,08:30:00 246.1417 # incorrect
# 26     0          3097 2023-12-23,08:38:00 690.9000 # incorrect


data |> 
  mutate(
    starts = cumsum(zoo::rollapply(pac_w == 0, 4, align="left", partial=TRUE, FUN=all)),
    prev_pac_w = lag(pac_w)
  ) |>
  summarize(
    .by = starts,
    date_time = first(date_time),
    lost = if (first(pac_w) == 0) {
      sum(mean(c(first(prev_pac_w), pac_w[which(pac_w > 0)[1]+2])) -
            pac_w[1:(which(pac_w > 0)[1]+1)]) / 60
    } else NA
  )

# starts           date_time     lost
# 1      0 2023-12-23,08:13:00       NA
# 2      1 2023-12-23,08:15:00 251.8333 # correct
# 3      2 2023-12-23,08:30:00 187.3167 # correct
# 4      3 2023-12-23,08:38:00 269.9167 # correct
```

Comment: If you have four `0`s and the value before them is 400, how do you intend to deal with it? Do you skip this period completely, or do you use the value before 400 as the basis for the average?

Comment: @r2evans, I analyzed the data and verified that the energy generated only has significant values between 06:20 and 16:40. I also didn't find failures caused by overvoltage outside these times, so I simply filtered the data: time >= '06:20:00' & time <= '16:40:00'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*: perhaps a run-length encoding approach is best. Now using the updated data with three "four 0s" blocks.

```r
r <- rle(data$pac_w == 0)
# ignore first or last, we cannot recover when those are the case
four0 <- setdiff(which(r$values), c(1L, length(r$values)))
# ignore those where we don't have sufficient data after the episode
four0 <- four0[r$lengths[four0 + 1] >= 3]
sapply(four0, function(f0) {
  indprev <- sum(r$lengths[1:(f0-1)])
  indtween <- (sum(r$lengths[1:(f0-1)])+1):(sum(r$lengths[1:f0])+2)
  indnext <- max(indtween)+1
  sum(
    mean(data$pac_w[ c(indprev, indnext) ]) - data$pac_w[indtween]
  ) / 60
})
# [1] 251.8333 187.3167 269.9167
```

If you need each value identified with a timestamp, then perhaps

```r
lapply(four0, function(f0) {
  indprev <- sum(r$lengths[1:(f0-1)])
  indtween <- (sum(r$lengths[1:(f0-1)])+1):(sum(r$lengths[1:f0])+2)
  indnext <- max(indtween)+1
  val <- sum(
    mean(data$pac_w[ c(indprev, indnext) ]) - data$pac_w[indtween]
  ) / 60
  cbind(data[indprev+1,], data.frame(lost = val))
}) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
#    pac_w day_energy_wh           date_time     lost
# 3      0          2555 2023-12-23,08:15:00 251.8333
# 18     0          2979 2023-12-23,08:30:00 187.3167
# 26     0          3097 2023-12-23,08:38:00 269.9167
```

---

Previous answer that requires four in a row:

```r
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(
    starts = cumsum(zoo::rollapply(pac_w == 0, 4, align="left", partial=TRUE, FUN=all)),
    prev_pac_w = lag(pac_w)
  ) |>
  summarize(
    .by = starts,
    date_time = first(date_time),
    lost = if (first(pac_w) == 0) {
      sum(mean(c(first(prev_pac_w), pac_w[which(pac_w > 0)[1]+2])) -
            pac_w[1:(which(pac_w > 0)[1]+1)]) / 60
      } else NA
  )
#   starts           date_time     lost
# 1      0 2023-12-23 08:13:00       NA
# 2      1 2023-12-23 08:15:00 251.8333
```

The `NA` row is not a time-lost, so you can safely `|> filter(!is.na(lost))`.

This is doing a rolling window, 4-wide, to find where a sequence of 4 zeroes starts; the `cumsum` then groups all rows based on the start of each of these sequence. From there, per-group (`.by=starts`) it internally selects the third non-zero `pac_w` and does your formula. (There is likely a way to clean that up, it looks rather "busy" as it stands.)

The use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer; if you have an older version, change from `mutate(.by=c(..), stuff)` to `group_by(..) |> mutate(stuff) |> ungroup()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response!

I now see that there are situations where there are not just four consecutive zeros. I have found, so far, one case with five consecutive zeros and this causes an error:
```
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `lost = if (...) NULL`.
ℹ In group 12: `starts = 11`.
Caused by error in `1:(which(pac_w > 0)[1] + 1)`:
! NA/NaN argument
```

Would you know how to solve it?

Comment: @CarlosLessa yes, I suspected that might be the case, I think RLE may work, see my edit.

Comment: r2evans, I edited it, added more rows to the dataset and included the results of your two solutions.

Comment: Bug in my indexing, see my edit @CarlosLessa. If I got it wrong, please post what you expect the return values to be.